# Limit definition

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Definition of limit:
$f:(U\subset\mathbb{R})  \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ has a a limit $l$ at $a$ iff:

Given any $\varepsilon>0$ $\exists\delta>0$ $\forall x \in U$ st. $0<|x-a| < \delta\implies |f(x)-l| < \varepsilon$

However if we have say $y \in U$ st  $0<|y-a| <|x-a|$

Given any $\varepsilon>0$ $\exists\delta>0$ $ y \in U$ st. $0<|y-a| < \delta\implies |f(y)-l| < \varepsilon$

However is it true from the above that:

Given any $\varepsilon>0$ $\exists\delta>0$ $\forall x \in U$ st. $0<|x-a| < \delta\implies |f(y)-l| < \varepsilon$ ?

If so please elaborate

Comment: Your last implication says $|x - a| < \delta$ implies $|f(y) - l| < \epsilon$.  How are $x$ and $y$ related?

Comment: This does not make sense, at least to me.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to construct an implication where you know some information about the input $x$, and this leads to some information on the image of the input $y$, but I can't check if this implication holds without knowing how $x$ and $y$ are related.  Is $y \in U$?

Comment: @user46944 Yes it is, x and y are related by the third line in my OP

Comment: In order to get a well-behaved definition of the limit, you need to specify that $ a $ is a **limit point** of $ U $. Otherwise, any $ l \in \mathbb{R} $ can be shown to be a limit of $ f $ at $ a $ simply by picking a sufficiently small $ \delta \in \mathbb{R}_{> 0} $ for each $ \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}_{> 0} $ such that the statement $ x \in U \cap (a - \delta,a + \delta) $ has truth value $ \mathsf{F} $.

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error, in that $y$ is not actually bound in your last statement. This means your last statement is simply ill-formed, unless $y$ is constant, which it isn't, because it depends on $x$ which *is* bound in the sentence.

What you seem to want is:

$$\forall \varepsilon > 0 \: \exists \delta > 0 \: (|x-a| < \delta \wedge |y-a|<|x-a|) \Rightarrow |f(y)-l|<\varepsilon.$$

But this is trivially true when $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)=l$. By assuming $|x-a|<\delta$ and $|y-a|<|x-a|$ we conclude $|y-a|<\delta$. So $|f(y)-l|<\varepsilon$ by the original statement. (There is nothing special about the name $x$; replacing every $x$ in your original statement with $y$ changes nothing about its meaning.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem, I think, is in how you are quantifying the last part and also your understanding of the role of $y$: 
$$
(\forall\epsilon>0)(\exists\delta>0)(\forall x\in U)(0<|x-a|<\delta\to|f(y)-l|<\epsilon).\tag{1}
$$
In $(1)$, you are saying *for all $\epsilon$* (where this $\epsilon$ presumably relates $x$ and $y$ somehow), but there is no indication as to what $y$ actually is.

---

Is $y\in U$?

- If no, then I do not understand the question.
- If yes, then *you* do not understand the question (or, more accurately, the definition of a limit).

However, I think I may have an idea as to what you are getting at, and I will try to address that as best as possible.

---

Saying $\forall x\in U$ or $\forall y\in U$ and then going on to say $0<|y-a|<|x-a|<\delta$ is actually **nonsensical** because $x$ and $y$ both represent all values in $U$. What I think you are *trying* to get at is how to get a "more accurate" limit; that is, you want to reduce your error tolerance $\epsilon$ by as much as possible, and you thought having $0<|y-a|<|x-a|<\delta$ would do this for you, but there is actually no need for this since $x$ represents *all* values in $U$. This means that you can make $\epsilon$ as small as you want--you just have to make sure you choose your $\delta$ appropriately, where this $\delta$ is related to $x$ by the $|x-a|<\delta$ expression.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially this is true. If, $\forall y \in U$, we have line 3 (not $y \in U$, this  doesn't really say much) leading directly to line 4. Line 6 is then true because the definition of limits you use doesn't allow $f(y)$ to deviate from $l$ by anything more than $\epsilon$.

It should probably read:

Given any ε>0  ∃δ>0  ∀x,y∈U  st. 0<|y-a|<|x−a|<δ⟹|f(y)−l|<ε  ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the question needs some editing, because it is not clear what you are asking exactly, and people need to guess.

The quatification on x and y is important, and depending on different quantification the statement may be true or false.

Do you mean the following?

$\lim_{x\to a}{f(x)}=l \ \ \ \ $ iff $  \ \ \ \ \forall \epsilon > 0 \ \ \exists \delta >0 \ ; \  \forall x,y \in U \  \ \  0<|y-a|<|x-a|<\delta  \ \ \Rightarrow \ \  |f(y)-l|<\epsilon$

If this is your question then it is true, but the use of $y$ is redundant, because whatever value for $y$ you choose you could have chosen it for $x$ without the need to mention $y$ (because of the universal quantifier).